# Paperclip error while trying to upload a file (windows)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I am new to rails and I am trying to upload a file using the **Paperclip Gem** but I am facing the following error. (Note I am using windows so it might be a problem with some file commands).

> Note I did install GnuWin31 and added the path C:\Program Files
> (x86)\GnuWin32\bin

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nk1Jd.png)

Comment: Did you have this in your model? has_attached_file :avatar, styles: { medium: "300x300>", thumb: "100x100>" }, default_url: "/images/:style/missing.png"
  validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\z/

Comment: yes, I have added it.